# $\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/(u^2+u-v^3+v)$ is torsion free over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Literally,

$B:=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/(u^2+u-v^3+v)$ is torsion free over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Note that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion-free_module : from contents in the 'Examples of torsion-free modules' in the link, it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, B:= \mathbb{Z}[u,v]/(u^2+u-v^3+v))=0$. By using the long exact sequence associated from $ 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ (noting that each $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ are flat over $\mathbb{Z}$ ), to show that, it suffices to show that the morphism $ i : \mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B \to \mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B $ is injective. Note that $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B \cong B:= \mathbb{Z}[u,v]/I $  and $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B \cong \mathbb{Q}[u,v]/I\mathbb{Q}[u,v] $ (?), where $I:=(u^2+u-v^3+v)$. Is the injectivity true? Or is there any other route to show the torsion-freeness of the $B$?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out other point of view. Perhaps, you mean, such a kind of basis implies the freeness of the $B$ over $\mathbb{Z}$? Or not?

Comment: Thank you. I wil try to it. I never thought I could prove it so easily using the concept of (like) the Groebner bases. :)

Comment: Fair enough, but I think that also Gröbner bases are overkill here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows easily from two standard lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** If $f \in R[T]$ is monic, then $R[T]/\langle f \rangle$ is a free $R$-module.

In fact, $\{[T^i] : 0 \leq i < \deg(f)\}$ is a basis, a consequence of polynomial divison.

**Lemma 2.** If $M$ is a free $S$-module and $S$ is an $R$-algebra which is a free $R$-module, then $M$ is a free $R$-module.

Again, you can write down the basis. If $B$ is an $S$-basis of $M$ and $C$ is an $R$-basis of $S$, then $M \cong \bigoplus_{b \in B} S \cong \bigoplus_{b \in B} \bigoplus_{c \in C} R \cong \bigoplus_{(b,c) \in B \times C} R$. The preimage of $e_{b,c}$ is $cb$, so that $CB$ is an $R$-basis of $M$.

It follows from Lemma 1 that $\mathbb{Z}[U,V] / \langle U^2+U -V^3 +V \rangle = \mathbb{Z}[V]\bigl[U\bigr] / \langle U^2+U  + (-V^3 +V) \rangle$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}[V]$-module. Also, $\mathbb{Z}[V]$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Hence, $\mathbb{Z}[U,V] / \langle U^2+U -V^3 +V \rangle$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module by Lemma 2. The proof shows: The set $\{[U^i V^j] : 0 \leq i < 2, \, j \geq 0\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I understand your overall strategy :) And what is the definition of $CB$? The set of scalar multiplications $\{ c \cdot b  : c\in C \subseteq S , b\in B \subseteq M \}$?  Even if M is not an S-algebra, Lemma 2 is sufficient, right?

Comment: Yes, this is $CB$. I don't understand the 2nd question.

Comment: O.K. Thanks. It's no big deal. My second question asks that even if we don't replace the condition "$M$ is a free $S$-module" by "$M$ is a $S$-algebra which is a free as a module", Lemma 2 still holds.

Comment: Lemma 2 also holds for $S$-algebras $M$, this is a special case. But the proof doesn't use the algebra structure. So it is better to formulate it for modules. (Still not sure if this answers your question.)

Comment: O.k. I got it. Thank you. Simple and Clear argument!

Answer (score 2):

One reasonably versatile approach, which also works in the non-commutative setting, is the following.

First, use the relations to obtain a nice spanning set. For example, we can use the relation $u^2=v^3-u-v$ to quickly deduce that the quotient ring $B$ is spanned as a $\mathbb Z$-module by $v^n,uv^n$ for $n\geq0$.

Second, construct one (or maybe several) modules with appropriate basis to deduce that there are no further relations/torsion elements. Here we can use the free abelian group $M$ having basis $y^n,xy^n$ for $n\geq0$. We turn this into a module over $\mathbb Z[u,v]$ by defining
$$ u\cdot y^n = xy^n, \quad u\cdot xy^n = y^{n+3}-y^{n+1}-xy^n, \quad
v\cdot y^n = y^{n+1}, \quad v\cdot xy^n = xy^{n+1}. $$
It is easy to see that $u+u^2+v-v^3$ acts as zero, so $M$ becomes a $B$-module.

Finally, take an arbitrary element of $B$, written as a finite linear combination of the spanning set $v^n,uv^n$, say $b=\sum \alpha_nv^n+\sum\beta_nuv^n$. Then in $M$ we have
$$ b \cdot 1 = \sum\alpha_ny^n + \sum\beta_nxy^n, $$
so the linear independence in $M$ tells us that $b=0$ if and only if $\alpha_n=\beta_n=0$ for all $n$.

A more involved example of this approach can be found for example in Lusztig's book 'Introduction to Quantum Groups' Proposition 3.2.4, where he proves the triangular decomposition by considering infinitely many Verma modules, indexed by pairs of scalars.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. How can you consider such (a priori) difficult(?) method? Anyway It seems fancy and interesting approach and your way seems to apply more general situation. Thank you. And can I ask question more? The set $\{ y^n, xy^n : n \ge 0 \}$ is really linearly independent in $M$ 'also over' $B:=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/I$, where $I:=(u^2+u-v^3+v)$ ? If so, then we may prove that  "if $b \cdot 1 = 0$ , then each $[\alpha_n] = [ \beta_n]= [0] $" ; i.e., $\alpha_n, \beta_n \in I$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $M$ is defined to be a free abelian group with a given basis, and then we give it the structure of a $B$-module. This doesn’t change the fact that $M$ is still a free abelian group.

Comment: O.K. Remains some delicated issue. Let me follow your comment.  Let $[\alpha_n] , [\beta_m] \in B:=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/I$ be elements such that $\Sigma [ \alpha_n]y^n + \Sigma [\beta_m] xy^m =0$. Then by the freeness of $M$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ and the scalar multiplication structre of $M$ over $B$, each $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficients of $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_m$ are zero so that $\alpha_n$ , $\beta_m$ are zero.  Correct argument? If not, at least $\alpha_n , \beta_m \in I$ is true?

Comment: $B$ is generated as an abelian group ($\mathbb Z$-module) by $v^n$ and $uv^n$, so the coefficients $\alpha_n,\beta_n$ are integers.

Comment: O.K. I think that I understand that coefficients of $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ are integers. But to show the linear independence over "$B$" I think that it will be good if we investigate through some concrete examples to check that. ( To me it doesn't seem directly transparent. ) Anyway it is surprising how can you think such clever (?) argument. For you, such an argument is somewhat standard in certain area? Anyway thank you.

Comment: @Mariano Suarez Alvarez : Aha really? I'll need to do some more investigation

Answer (score 0):

That the $i$ in my question is injective is true !

I also upload the my own answers I tried as a record. I will follow the approach suggested in the question.

- 1. Let $l(u,v) := u^2+u-v^3+v \in \mathbb{Z}[u,v]$. Let's view the $l$ as polynomial of indeterminate $u$ whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}[v]$ ; i.e., $l \in \mathbb{Z}[v][u]$. Note that $l(u-v)= u^2 + (1-2v)u + v^2 -v^3 \in \mathbb{Z}[v][u]$ and $1-2v$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[v]$ and satisfies the sufficient conditions of the Eisenstein's Criterion (True?) so that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[v]$ . Thus, $l(u)$ is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[v]$ by the Hungerford, Algebra, p.166, Exercise 10-(a) ! :

[image]

So, $(l) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[u,v]$ is prime ideal.

- 2. Next, as I worte in the question, to show that "$B:=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/(u^2+u-v^3+v)$ is torsion free over $\mathbb{Z}$" , it suffices to show that $\operatorname{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, B:= \mathbb{Z}[u,v]/(u^2+u-v^3+v))=0$.  From the long exact sequence associated from $ 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ (noting that each $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ are flat over $\mathbb{Z}$ ), to show that, it suffices to show that the morphism $ i : \mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B\cong B \to \mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B \cong \mathbb{Q}[u,v]/I\mathbb{Q}[u,v] $ is injective.
- 3. Now we can show that the $i$ is injective. Let $f+I \in B:=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]/I$ (where $I:=(l(u,v))$) such that $i(f+I) = 0 + I\mathbb{Q}[u,v]$. Then $f \in I\mathbb{Q}[u,v]$ so that $f(u,v) = l(u,v) \cdot g(u,v)$ for some $g(u,v) \in \mathbb{Q}[u,v].$ Let $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ be the product of the denominators of the coefficients of $g(u,v)$. Then $r\cdot g(u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}[u,v]$ (True?) and note that $r \cdot f(u,v) = r \cdot l(u,v)g(u,v) = l(u,v) \cdot r g(u,v) \in (l) $. So since $(l)$ is prime ideal $r \in (l)$ or $f(u,v) \in (l)$. Since $r \notin (l)$, $f\in I:=(l)$ and we are done.